# Does WebStorm have a "Code Cleanup" feature like ReSharper has?

Tags: ide, webstorm, resharper

I have (and love) ReSharper for all of my .NET Visual Studio coding.  I really love the code cleanup feature that does things like properly spacing code, killing unnecessary white space, alphabetizing CSS properties, etc.

Recently, I have started using WebStorm for a Node.JS project.  Does Webstorm have a similar code cleanup feature?  It's made by the same people that make Resharper so I thought it would have such a feature but I can't find it.

Comment: I suggest you asked the company who wrote the program they are in the best position to answer this question.

Comment: Wow, I guess that could apply for just about any question on SuperUser.  Does it occur that I may have done that already and that is why I am here?

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt I don't know anything about WebStorm, but I do want to mention that it's not worth taking Ramhound too seriously; I think he considers annoying people for no good reason to be his sole mission in life.

Answer (score 2):

A workflow similar to ReSharper's Code Cleanup was [introduced](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/07/try-intellij-idea-14-eap-138-1283-4-with-code-cleanup-android-studio-beta-features-and-more/) in IntelliJ IDEA 14 in late 2014.

Since WebStorm is based on IntelliJ IDEA platform, I assume that it's going to incorporate Code Cleanup soon as well. The current production version of WebStorm, v9, was released in October (that is, before IJ 14), making WebStorm 10 a good candidate to include Code Cleanup. Now, [WebStorm 10 Early Access Program (EAP)](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+10+EAP) doesn't list this change so far: either because it's not there so far or because the WS team just didn't include the feature in a summary of changes.

I'd say grab WebStorm 10 EAP and check if there's a *Code Cleanup* item under the *Analyze* menu, and if it's there, check that it's doing what you expect it to do.